# bootstrap-datetimepicker date time switchin gissue

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

When I try to switch between date and time in latest bootstrap datetimepicker
I can switch date to time once and I cannot switch back to date again. There are no console errors and the picker is not getting closed after the selection of the date and time.
HTML

```
<div  id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
    <input type="text"/>
    <span class="add-on">
       <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'
});
```

Comment: Use this .. https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/  ,this is bootstrap datetimepicker

Comment: using the same plugin, it is working fine when I run as a standalone package, when I use the same code in my project, The functionality is not working. I have checked with the versions used in my plugins, expect bootstrap and jquery I have updated the lib to given version. I wanted to know if someone has faced similar problem need to know workaround for this.